# Deploying lucene-surround QueryParser to Solr

Tags: lucene, solr

I am trying to deploy the Lucene-surround QueryParser to Solr (1.4.0)

I was told its as simple as downloading the surround QueryParser jar and adding it to the lib directory in solr.war, then referencing it in solrconfig.xml by adding the line

```
<queryParser name="SurroundQParser" class="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.surround.parser.QueryParser"/>
```

When I do that I receive this error

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating QParserPlugin,
 org.apache.lucene.queryParser.surround.parser.QueryParser is not a org.apache.s
olr.search.QParserPlugin
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:415)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:435)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1498)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1492)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1525)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initQParsers(SolrCore.java:1442)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:548)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:428)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:278)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContain
er.java:117)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.ja
va:83)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:99)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
40)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.ja
va:594)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:
500)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448
)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
40)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:147)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHan
dlerCollection.java:161)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
40)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection
.java:147)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
40)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:
117)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:
40)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to extend [QParserPlugin](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/QParserPlugin.html). 
[The Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#QParserPlugin) explains how - basically your `createParser` method should return the surround query parser instead of QParser. 
[Mark Miller's post](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/22/exploring-query-parsers/) suggests some alternatives.